# Paypal API Recurring Payments Balance

Tags: paypal

Sure it's just something I'm missing. Fairly new to the Paypal API, especially the classic one! Basically, I'm using the following code to generate a subscription to my site at £2.50 per month. I can get the subscription to appear in the Recurring Payments Dashboard on Paypal Sandbox, but it doesn't change the balance and seems to be missing things to do with the initial payment. I tried INITAMT too, which filled in some fields, but still doesn't change the Sandbox balance of my account. Any ideas guys? Here's the code:

```
    <?php
// Set PayPal API version and credentials.
$api_version = '85.0';
$api_endpoint = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp';
$api_username = 'MY_SANDBOX_USERNAME';
$api_password = 'MY_SANDBOX_PASSWORD';
$api_signature = 'MY_SANDBOX_SIGNATURE';

$startdate = gmdate('Y-m-d')."T00:00:00Z";
$request_params = array
               (
'USER' => $api_username, 
'PWD' => $api_password, 
'SIGNATURE' => $api_signature, 
'VERSION' => $api_version, 
'METHOD' => 'CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile',
'PROFILESTARTDATE' => $startdate,
'DESC' => 'Membership',
'BILLINGPERIOD' => 'Month',
'BILLINGFREQUENCY' => '1',
'TOTALBILLINGCYCLES' => '0',
'AMT' => '2.50',
'MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS' => '12',
'ACCT' => '4641631486853053',
'CREDITCARDTYPE' => 'VISA',
'CVV2' => '123',
'FIRSTNAME' => 'James',
'LASTNAME' => 'Smith',
'STREET' => 'FirstStreet',
'CITY' => 'London',
'STATE' => 'G London',
'ZIP' => 'W2 1NE',
'COUNTRYCODE' => 'GB',
'CURRENCYCODE' => 'GBP',
'EXPDATE' => '052015'
               );

// Loop through $request_params array to generate the NVP string.
$nvp_string = '';
foreach($request_params as $var=>$val)
{
   $nvp_string .= '&'.$var.'='.urlencode($val);   
}
// Send NVP string to PayPal and store response
$curl = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $api_endpoint);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvp_string);

$result = curl_exec($curl);      
curl_close($curl);
$nvp_response_array = parse_str($result);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your code and used my own sandbox credentials.  It seems to have worked just fine for me.

[image]

It came through as unclaimed since my account is USD, but you can see it did work just fine.  Are you sure you're checking the correct sandbox account after you run it yourself?

Comment: Yup! Using the right credentials. If I go into the Recurring Payments Dashboard, it all shows up there...but the balance definitely doesn't update.

Comment: Got it working! Was a currency issue rather than anything else! Thanks Andrew!